# URLs starting with http:// or https://, separated by comma, no spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need check a field where user insert URLs. The rules are:

- No spaces;
- Separated by comma;
- Each URL have to starts with http:// or https://

Valid examples of input text:

- "http://whatever.com,https://anything.edu,http://anotherurl.br"
- "http://thisisavalidurl.com"
- "https://aurl.fr"

Some invalid examples:

- "https://validurl.com,badexample.com"
- "anotherbadone.com"
- "nomoreideas.com,badurl.com"
- "https://goodone.com, http://goodbutspacesnotwelcomed.com"

This is my regex, but is not working properly:

```
/(^([\S]https?:\/\/)\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,})$*/i
```

Comment: What is not working properly?

Comment: What are you trying to match with `\S` in `[\S]https`? You are matching any non-whitespace character, but I would think that http would be the start of the string. And on top of that, you are trying to capture it.

Comment: Hi @UweKeim, as per rules, invalid urls are matching. For instance:
"htt://test.com,blahblahblah.com"

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, independently of removing \S, it does not work. I just shared the last attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual regex is not correct as it accepts any non whitespace character before `http` when you use `[\S]https` in the beginning of the regex.

What I can recommend is to use a combination of `Array` functions along with this **[regex](https://regex101.com/r/hotkUV/1)**, to make sure all the entered urls are correct.

First split the input value by comma and get urls array:

```
var urls = document.getElementById("urls").value.split(",");
urls = urls.map(u => u.trim()).filter(v => v !== '');
```

Then check that all urls matches the `/^https?:\/\/(\w+)\.\[a-z\]{2,3}$/` **[regex](https://regex101.com/r/hotkUV/1)**

```
let valid = urls.every(url => url.match(/^https?:\/\/(\w+)\.[a-z]{2,3}$/));
```

**Demo:**

```js
document.getElementById("urls").onchange = function() {
  var urls = document.getElementById("urls").value.split(",");
  urls = urls.map(u => u.trim()).filter(v => v !== '');
  console.log(urls);
  let valid = urls.every(url => url.match(/^https?:\/\/(\w+)\.[a-z]{2,3}$/) );
  console.log(valid);
}
```

```html
<input id="urls" />
```

Comment: Thank you @chŝdk. It seems to be working in most of the cases. But fails when allows white spaces. I think that a small adjustment is enough. ;)

Comment: @VitorEduardodaSilva Please take a look at my edited code using [this **regex**](https://regex101.com/r/hotkUV/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can try using something like this:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/\w+\.\w+,?)*$
```

This is pretty basic and doesn't offer extensive url verification, such as misspelling top-level domains for example (.com vs .cmo).

Just capture your pattern `https?:\/\/\w+\.\w+,?` and <strike>recurse `(?1)` it as needed</strike> allow for the optional comma `,`.

## [See it here](https://regex101.com/r/wUn0sI/2)

Comment: In my opinion this is the best ever. But this flavour is not supported by JS.

Comment: Ahh you're right. You actually don't even need to recurse the first capturing group at all - I had it in there when testing something out and forgot to remove it later. You could use [`^(https?:\/\/\w+\.\w+,?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/wUn0sI/2)